# Use Javascript to Write a Day in the Future

Tags: javascript, date

I found this code online. I was trying to get it to write the date 9 days from today, but I can't figure out how to do that. Does anyone know what to change in this code?

```
var d_names = new Array("Sunday,", "Monday,", "Tuesday,",
"Wednesday,", "Thursday,", "Friday,", "Saturday,");

var m_names = new Array("January ", "February ", "March ", 
"April ", "May ", "June ", "July ", "August ", "September ", 
"October ", "November ", "December ");

var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var sup = "";
if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date ==31)
   {
   sup = "st";
   }
else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22)
   {
   sup = "nd";
   }
else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23)
   {
   sup = "rd";
   }
else
   {
   sup = "th";
   }
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + m_names[curr_month] + curr_date + "<SUP>" +     sup   + "</SUP> " + " " + curr_year);
```

This formats the date like: Saturday, August 20th 2011

Comment: Where did you add 9 days in that code? I don't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after:

```
var d = new Date();
```

Write:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate()+9);
```

So you have:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+9);
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
```

Comment: better than mine.  The javascript date object is smarter than I thought it would be. :)

Comment: Problem: If the date is 28, the new date will be 37.. won't it?

Comment: @DominicB-c Now. The Javascript `Date` object is very robust and easy to use like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "getTime" method of the date object with returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 and then add the number of milliseconds in 9 days.

```
var d = new Date();
var date9Days = new Date(d.getTime()+777600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var meh = new Date();
var daysAhead = 9;
meh.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var newmeh = new Date(meh.getTime() + daysAhead * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

That's how you get now + 9 days.  Then just pass that date to your function

Answer (score 0):

```
var d_names = new Array("Sunday,", "Monday,", "Tuesday,",
"Wednesday,", "Thursday,", "Friday,", "Saturday,");

var m_names = new Array("January ", "February ", "March ", 
"April ", "May ", "June ", "July ", "August ", "September ", 
"October ", "November ", "December ");

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+9);
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var sup = "";

if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date ==31)
   {
   sup = "st";
   }
else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22)
   {
   sup = "nd";
   }
else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23)
   {
   sup = "rd";
   }
else
   {
   sup = "th";
   }
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

document.write(d_names[curr_day] + " " + m_names[curr_month] + curr_date + "<SUP>" +     sup   + "</SUP> " + " " + curr_year);
```